# c# how can I compare type of template type to builtin type on runtime

Tags: c#, generics, runtime

that code doesn't compile, anyone has any idea how to write this logic correctly?

```
public void FilBuff<T>(T p_tInput) 
    {
        if(typeid(p_tInput )== typeof(string))
        {
            m_bBuff = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)p_tInput);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typeof(T)`. Like this:

```
public void FilBuff<T>(T p_tInput) 
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        m_bBuff = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)p_tInput);
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, what you are doing with generics (not templates) is a little odd. It might be better to just use an overloaded method in your case.